# Login Script Difficulties?

Tags: php, html, session, authentication, localhost

I'm hoping some can help me with my login script. The code works perfectly when I run it from wamp localhost but when it goes up live on the server it returns a blank page when I try and login can anyone tell me why? The code is as follows.

```
<?php
session_start();

//login script
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'login'){

//give your login credentials here
if($_REQUEST['uname'] == 'zipbuzz' && $_REQUEST['pass'] == 'sewilt')
$_SESSION['login_user'] = 1;
else
$_SESSION['login_msg'] = 1;
}

//get the page name where to redirect
if(isset($_REQUEST['pagename']))
$pagename = $_REQUEST['pagename'];

//logout script
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'logout'){
unset($_SESSION['login_user']);
header('Location:login.php');
}
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
if(isset($_REQUEST['pagename']))
header('Location:'.$pagename.'.php');
else
header('Location:admin.php');
}else{
?>


<?php
//display the error msg if the login credentials are wrong!
if(isset($_SESSION['login_msg'])){
echo 'Wrong username and password !';
unset($_SESSION['login_msg']);
}
?>
```

then I add the following to the pages that need a login to access.

```
<?php session_start();
//check logged in or not!
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header('Location:login.php?pagename='.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"));
}
?>
```

Comment: Add this to the beginning of the script and check for errors: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: white screen of death = error checking\display are off

Comment: You're mixing bracketed and non-bracketed blocks (if statements). Don't do that! It's a maintenance nightmare.  As for the error you can check the server's error log. It should be there

Comment: I would suspect that you're breaking up your session with `<?php` above `//display the error msg if the login credentials are wrong!`

Comment: Plus this `}else{` underneath `header('Location:admin.php');` is broken/unmatched.

Answer (score 0):

You have `else{ ?>` that wasn't closed.

Comment: if i close the else statement i get Internal Server Error 500.

Answer (score 0):

First up, here's a corrected version of the code you posted.

```
<?php
session_start();
//login script
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'login')
{
    //give your login credentials here
    if($_REQUEST['uname'] == 'zipbuzz' && $_REQUEST['pass'] == 'sewilt')
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = 1;
    else
        $_SESSION['login_msg'] = 1;
}

//get the page name where to redirect
if(isset($_REQUEST['pagename']))
    $pagename = $_REQUEST['pagename'];

//logout script
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'logout')
{
    unset($_SESSION['login_user']);
    header('Location:login.php');
}
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['pagename']))
        header('Location:'.$pagename.'.php');
    else
        header('Location:admin.php');
}
else
{
    //display the error msg if the login credentials are wrong!
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_msg']))
    {
        echo 'Wrong username and password !';
        unset($_SESSION['login_msg']);
    }
}
?>
```

Besides that, there are several lines where you could use `session_write_close();` to make sure your session data and/or status is indeed saved/updated before you redirect to another URL. I didn't implement that in my above correction though. Take it as a training opportunity. ;)

Comment: Warning:session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/users/web/b197/ipg.brorboardsnet/cgi-bin/tmp/sess_938a7d2379acb25f093f48792420240d, O_RDWR) 
failed: No such file or directory (2) in /hermes/bosoraweb016/b197/ipg.brorboardsnet/sites/airbornmonkey/login.php on line 7

Warning:session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at 
/hermes/bosoraweb016/b197/ipg.brorboardsnet/sites/airbornmonkey/login.php:2) in /hermes/bosoraweb016/b197/ipg.brorboardsnet/sites/airbornmonkey/login.php on line 7
full screen background image

Comment: @user2480085 That first error (*Warning:session_start...No such file or directory*) tells you that the session can not be created because the related dir where session files are stored is not available, or does not exist. That's a **server configuration problem**, not a problem related to your PHP code! The following errors are triggered because the first error is printed to screen. That's normal. So, to keep it short: your server config is not correct. You'll have to fix that so PHP can find the directory where temporary session files are stored.

Comment: thanks e-sushi that should do it. and thanks everyone else for your help too.